# Auto login and redirect after registration

Tags: jsf-2

I am creating a movie rental application using JSF 2.0 with Primefaces 3.4.1 as frontend. After a user is successfully registered, I need to automatically login with the newly created ID and redirect to the home page.

Currently, I am doing this way:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RegistrationBean extends BaseBean implements Serializable
{
   ...

   public String register() 
   {
      String nextPage = null;
      User userDetails = new User();

      try 
      {
         BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDetails, this);
         int registrationID = getServiceLocator().getUserService().registerUser(userDetails);
         LOGGER.info("Registered user successfully. Registration ID - {}", registrationID);

         // auto login
         LoginBean loginBean = (LoginBean)FacesUtils.getManagedBean("loginBean");
         loginBean.setUserId(userID);
         loginBean.setPassword(password);
         loginBean.login();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         LOGGER.error("Error during registration - " + e.getMessage());
         FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null, 
                  FacesUtils.getValueFromResource(RESOURCE_BUNDLE, REGISTRATION_FAIL));
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
      }
      return nextPage;
   }
}
```

**LoginBean** :

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean extends BaseBean implements Serializable
{
   ...

   public String login() 
   {
      FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

      try 
      {
         currentUser = getServiceLocator().getUserService().findUser(userID);

         if (currentUser == null) 
         {
            ctx.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null, 
                     FacesUtils.getValueFromResource(RESOURCE_BUNDLE, UNKNOWN_LOGIN)));
            return (userID = password = null);
         }
         else 
         {
            if (EncryptionUtils.compareHash(password, currentUser.getEncrPass())) {
               return INDEX + "?faces-redirect=true";
            }
            else 
            {
               ctx.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null, 
                        FacesUtils.getValueFromResource(RESOURCE_BUNDLE, AUTH_FAIL)));
               return null;
            }
         }
      }
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
         final String errorMessage = "Error occured during login - " + e.getMessage();
         LOGGER.error(errorMessage);
         ctx.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null, errorMessage));
      }

      return null;
   }
}
```

Above approach in `register()` method is, no doubt, wrong and insecure. Is there any way I can achieve the same in a cleaner way ??

---

**Implementation using [f:viewParam](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6377798/1055089)**

**RegistrationBean**

```
int registrationID = getServiceLocator().getUserService().registerUser(userDetails);
LOGGER.info("Registered user successfully. Registration ID - {}", registrationID);
nextPage = LOGIN + "?faces-redirect=true&id=" + registrationID;
```

**login.xhtml**

```
<f:metadata>
   <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{loginBean.regID}" />
   <f:event listener="#{loginBean.autoLogin}" type="preRenderView"></f:event>
</f:metadata>
```

**LoginBean**

```
private int regID;

...

public void autoLogin()
{
   if (regID > 0 && !FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback())
   {
      currentUser = getServiceLocator().getUserService().findUser(regID);
      NavigationHandler navHandler = FacesUtils.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
      navHandler.handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null, INDEX + "?faces-redirect=true");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let us assume you are having three pages

1. Register/User Signup
2. Login
3. Home page

Here successful registration need auto login and needs to be redirected to home page but usually manual login is must after registration.

Anyhow, I would suggest you to separate login credential check in separate method in a facade class or you can have it in LoginBean too.

```
public User doLogin(String userName, String password) {
     // query user
     // match with password
     // return null if not found or not matched
}
```

Add `navigation-rule` in `faces-config.xml` for registration bean and login bean

```
 <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>loginSuccess</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/home.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
 </navigation-case>
```

In both registration bean and login bean call `doLogin` method then if user found set navigation

```
NavigationHandler nh = facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
nh.handleNavigation(facesContext, null, "loginSuccess");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is there any way, that I can forward the call to the `login()` method in LoginBean since `doLogin()` does the same thing.

Comment: yes you can do that. forward registration page to login page with param then in login bean param found in request, process it.

Comment: I was able to implement your suggestion using <f:viewParam> with preRenderView event listener. I am updating my post to reflect the same. Thanks for the suggestion. Please let me know if you can suggest any improvements to my implementation.